# How do I pass command to stack GHCi repl from command line

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I want to say something like:

> stack ghci exec ':browse! *Main' | grep Button

Is it possible to pass a command to stack ghci and then use the result in grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe the commands into GHCi from the shell:

```
echo ':browse! *Main' | stack ghci | grep Button
```